# Adding an object value after an array.map in javascript

Tags: javascript

Discovering functionnal programming, I'm facing many questions with javascript syntax and possibilities.

Actually, I have a function doing this (`cooVersPoints` returns an object) :

**Function call** :

```
obj = data.map( dataVersPoints )[0];
```

**dataVersPoints** :

```
const dataVersPoints = data => {
    const points = data.coo.map( cooVersPoints )
    points.id = data.id 
    return points
}
```

I would like to write something like this :

```
const dataVersPoints = data => data.coo.map( cooVersPoints ).concat({ id: data.id})
```

But the output is now different. I get now :

```
0: {points: Array(2), voisin: Array(0)}
1: {points: Array(2), voisin: Array(0)}
2: {points: Array(2), voisin: Array(0)}
3: {points: Array(2), voisin: Array(0)}
4: {id: "canvas"}
```

While I need/use this format :

```
0: {points: Array(2), voisin: Array(0)}
1: {points: Array(2), voisin: Array(0)}
2: {points: Array(2), voisin: Array(0)}
3: {points: Array(2), voisin: Array(0)}
id: "canvas"
```

Is there a way to do this ?
By the way, is this actually seems functional ?

Comment: JS has Arrays and Objects. Arrays have a numerical index starting at 0, Objects have keys. You cannot have a hybrid. Use `{ id: "canvas", points: [...] }`

Comment: While you can do this `const dataVersPoints = data => Object.assign(data.coo.map(cooVersPoints),{ id: data.id})` - mistreating array's like that is frowned upon :p

Comment: @ChrisG actually - you can. Arrays *are* Objects.

Comment: Hello Jean and welcome to Stack overflow. I don't understand why you would map the entire array if you only need the first element. You could try the following: `const dataVersPoints = data => data.coo.map( cooVersPoints ).concat(data.id)` And then call the function like this: `obj = dataVersPoints(data[0])`

Comment: @Lux I'm actually in favor of lying to beginners so they don't use weird hacks that might behave inconsistently across browsers and engines. If that is frowned upon on stackoverflow, I'll stop doing it.

Comment: Hello all, thks for replies. 
>ChrisG, JaromandaX, Lux : It seemed usefull when I tried to map the object as an array : It only uses the array-like part. 
>HMR : You're right, I figured aksing this was a confusion. I put it off.

Comment: I would have said you *should* not do this. But lying can in fact confuse people when they try to understand existing code. Also especially the fact that arrays are objects is totally part of the standard. JeanGrimbert for you I would definitly would do what ChrisG said. Just wrap id and array in an object.